# Memory issue in my rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a quite small Rails 3.1.1 application that rack up memory at lightning speed. 8-10 clicks in the application and I'm up to almost 1gb of RAM used.

We checked the log for slow running MYSQL queries, nothing there. We also checked Apache log, nothing there.

The application is running with Passenger 3.0

Can this issue be bound to some gem that is used? This application started as a Rails 3.0.1 application, and we updated the rails version. There are still [deprecated?] references in the gemfile. Here is the gemfile :

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.1.1"
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.6"
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.6'
gem 'json'

group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails", "~> 3.1.4"
  gem "coffee-rails", "~> 3.1.1"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'capistrano'
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you, some how using memory table?

Comment: Missed that comment, sorry! No, there is no memory table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about eliminating possibilities. Some directions:

- Does the application run in development mode? Is there a difference in memory usage in development / production mode?
- Try staying on one page, in one controller. Monitor the memory continuously. Is it going up? Is it only one controller or in all controllers? If it is in one controller only, you have a smaller codebase to check.
- Memory profile your application with tools like [Bleakhouse](http://www.rubyinside.com/bleakhouse-tool-to-find-memory-leaks-in-your-rails-applications-470.html), [Memorylogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/memorylogic), [Scout](https://scoutapp.com/) or [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/). Check the memory hotspots to find the memory hog.
- Eliminate dependencies one by one, to see if a bug in another gem is causing the problem.
- Try a different server, like Mongrel, WEBrick or Unicorn. If the behaviour is different, it could be Passenger.
- Try a different Ruby version to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for this checklist. I can already tell you that on development (webrick), it does not have any memory issue. It's only on production server. Both production and dev uses ruby 1.8.7, so it's not ruby version either. The application used to work on older passenger version (2.x). The morning they installed Passenger 3.0, it started to "leak" memory. I'm pretty sure the problem is Passenger, but I'm unable to "prove" it. I'll start looking for memory profiling with the tools you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure I've narrowed it down to Passenger being the faulty one... when I click on a link and then wait, let's say 1 minute, the next click will make the application crash. The ruby process never stops growing until my host kill it at 750mb. The application is pretty small and straitghforward, I can't really believe that an application with about 20 records in the database can take up to 750mb of RAM. The is no big processes in ruby code that could take that much memory...

Comment: You can try the 'passenger-memory-stats' http://www.netadmintools.com/art626.html tool to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because therubyracer gem.

therubyracer with passenger make memroy leak.

delete therubyracer gem or use 0.7.5 version

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *slow* queries, check for *inefficient* queries -- that is, the kind that load lots of records from the DB, create lots of objects, and then loop over them on the Ruby side.

Or use a profiler such as New Relic.

Comment: There are about 20 total records in the database. Forgot to mention that!

Comment: Then it's probably not the DB! :)

Comment: Yeah I don't think so either ;-)